# How to start an exe in C++ and get its HWND (window handle) for sending messages

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to start a program, in this case OBS Studio so I can programmatically send it keystrokes to start/stop recording. However, I need the HWND for the sendInput method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx

I assume that is the best way to do it, I just need to send something like 'shift+f1' to OBS. I figure the best way to get it is to start up OBS in C++ and then get its HWND somehow. But I cannot seem to figure that out. Any ideas?

It would also work, if we could just send a global keypress. Without needing to have the window in the foreground.

Comment: Did you create the process?  Here's one way to do it.  Store off its process id. Write an [EnumWindowsProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633498(v=vs.85).aspx) that given an HWND compares against the stored process id.  Call [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) with your callback function.

Comment: Um, there is no `HWND` parameter for the `SendInput` function.

Comment: Think about it from the OS perspective. How does it know which HWND is the real app (presuming it has a HWND in the first place), and which ones are splash screens, EULA dialogs, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the process ID of the spawned process, you can find its top-level window by iterating through all windows under desktop:

```
DWORD dwProcessId, dwPid = 0;
HWND hWnd;

dwProcessId = ... // Spawn process and get its process ID

for (hWnd = ::FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
     hWnd != NULL;
     hWnd = ::FindWindowEx(NULL, hWnd , NULL, NULL)) {
    ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwPid);
    if (dwPid == dwProcessId) break;
}

_ASSERTE (hWnd != NULL);  // Or better do some error checking
// hWnd found, do whatever you need
```